# Obtener datos en Firebase Android

Tags: android, base-de-datos, firebase

quisiera saber como puedo obtener datos de una base de datos firebase, actualmente puedo agregar los datos, pero no se como consultar esos datos.

Asi esta mi nodo en firebase:
[image: data]

Si quisiera traer el campo "nombre" de ese usuario, que tendria que hacer? He utilizado dataSnapshot y todo eso, pero me trae todos los nombres que hay en la base de datos, solo quisiera traer un nombre especifico.

En resumen... Estos datos los agrego mediante un registro, tengo habilitado la funcion de autentificacion de email de firebase, luego de registrarme cuando inicio sesion todo perfecto, pero deseo solo traer el nombre del usuario actual, es decir si ese id esta logueado, entonces solo traer el nombre de "Ibrahim".

Espero me hayan comprendido lo que deseo realizar.

Comment: Agrega lo que haz tratado, podría ser de utilidad para alguién que intenta lo mismo que tu, revisa [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para traer esos datos hace lo siguiente

```
 // Agregamos un listener a la referencia
    ref.child("Usuario").child(userID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

       if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
          String nombre = dataSnapshot.child("nombre").getValue(String.class);
          String numero = dataSnapshot.child("Numero").getValue(String.class);
          String FechaNacimiento = dataSnapshot.child("FechaNacimiento").getValue(String.class);
          String sexo = dataSnapshot.child("sexo").getValue(String.class);
     }
        //ya tenemos los datos desde Firebase, podemos actualizar la UI

      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        System.out.println("Fallo la lectura: " + databaseError.getCode());
      }
    });
```

donde userID es el valor alfanumerico donde se guardan todos los valores de tu nodo.

```
String userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

Donde mAuth es

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

y donde ref es la referencia a la base de datos que se obtiene de la siguiente manera

```
DatabaseReference ref;
ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

**Importante**

Recorda que los valores que traes de Firebase se traen asyncronamente, por lo que no vas a poder acceder a esos datos fuera del `dataSnapshot`, ya que si aun no los trajo, te va a arrojar null. Y siempre recorda usar `dataSnapshot.exists()` para asegurarte de que tenes valores en ese nodo y no te tire otro NPE tratando de ir a una referencia nula.

Otro tip es no usar siempre el tipo de dato String para guardar todos los datos en tu base de datos, tene en cuenta que cada tipo de variable tiene reservado un cierto espacio en memoria, no es lo mismo String que int, aunque no se note en performance, es mejor guardar numeros que no superen los 2 bytes (16 bits) en enteros y no usar String ya que estamos asignando mas memoria al inicializar esa variable, pero como te decia, no es un impacto importante para tener en cuenta, es mas algo de diseño.

Otro tip es guardar la fecha como timestamp y no como `dd/mm/yy` , si la guardas como timestamp vas a poder ordenar usuarios por fecha de nacimiento , y podes obtener el timestamp desde el cliente y transformarlo a fecha con un `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: Muchas gracias por la solucion, entendi a la perfección. Solo quisiera consultar el segundo parrafo donde hablas de los tipos de datos, por ejemplo en el campo "numero" en mi clase lo tengo como un int, pero no se como declararlo en la base de datos como un entero, ya que es la primera vez que utilizo una base de datos nosql, en sql si se como seleccionar el tipo de campo de un dato, como lo harias en el caso de firebase? @gastón-saillén

Comment: en el setValue vas a mandar el int y no String, cualquier cosa podes formular otra pregunta de como enviar datos con el codigo que usas para generar esa estructura, un saludo

Comment: te recomiendo ver este video , es muy util https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ran_Ylug7AE

Comment: Hola, tengo otro problema, el uid o id que genera por cada usuario, quisiera extraerlo para guardarlo en un campo de cada usuario, como lo puedo hacer?

Comment: Tienes algun correo o algun lugar donde te pueda escribir para ver si me ayudas con mis dudas acerca de firebase?

Comment: Puedes publicar preguntas y estoy siempre vigilando este TAG :-)